# Change the URL paths in the stylesheet dynamically in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

(I posted this to the WordPress stack exchange, but I also think its a good idea to post this here).

I found a function that when placed in the functions.php, it injects the entire stylesheet into the head on the website:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'internal_css_print' );
function internal_css_print() {
  echo '<style>';

  include_once get_template_directory() . '/style.css';

  echo '</style>';
}
```

It works great, the whole stylesheet goes in the head just fine, but one minor issue is that the URLs in the CSS are broken. For example when the following is in the CSS file:

```
background: url('images/hero-desktop.jpg');
```

When the stylesheet is linked normally, this returns `http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/hero-desktop.jpg`-> works

But when the stylesheet is injected in the head it returns: `http://localhost:8888/images/hero-desktop.jpg` --> doesn't work. The path is broken.

To fix this I can do a simple search and replace in the css to change `url('` to `url('/wp-content/themes/my-theme/` but there has to be a better way.

So I was thinking is there something to add to the function at the top, so before spitting out the whole CSS file into the head, it dynamically changes the URL paths from `url(/images/)` to `/wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/`. If this is possible that would be great so its just a one time setup instead of searching and replacing CSS on an already developed site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to extend an existing stylesheet using [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style). This is probably the "most correct" way to do this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_styles' );
function add_custom_styles(){
    $style_handle = 'style';
    $custom_css   = 'body {
        background: url('. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/hero-desktop.jpg);
    }';

    wp_add_inline_style( $style_handle, $custom_css );
}
```

Of course, replace `style` with the handle for the stylesheet you want to extend.

---

Another method of doing this is to use a "PHP CSS" file like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'print_internal_css' );
function print_internal_css(){
    echo '<style>';
        include get_stylesheet_directory().'/style.css.php';
    echo '</style>';
}
```

**style.css.php**:

```
body {
    background: url( <?= get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/hero-desktop.jpg'; ?> );
}
```

---

Lastly, if you just want a quick-fix for what you have, you can just run your file through a simple `str_replace` function, and use `file_get_contents` or a cURL request instead of include:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'print_internal_css' );
function print_internal_css(){
    echo '<style>';
        $styles = file_get_contents( get_stylesheet_directory().'/style.css' );
        echo str_replace( "url('", "url('/wp-content/themes/my-theme/", $styles );
    echo '</style>';
}
```

Comment: awesome looks like the last str_replace will work for me. thank you!

Comment: Since WordPress 3.3 [wp_print_styles ](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_styles)should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts

Comment: I haven't used [`wp_print_styles`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_styles) to `enqueue` a stylesheet - however reading deeper into make, it does appear that it's not actually limited to `enqueued` scripts, and anything on that hook can bleed into `wp_editor()`. @cup_of - Since you're using the latter function, you may want to consider keeping it in `wp_head`